# Check is_single() outside loop

Tags: posts

How can I check if an Id `is_single()` outside the loop in a plugin?

When I try it I always get a fatal error
The code

```
 add_action('transition_post_status', 'pmc_update_notification',10,3);

function pmc_update_notification($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
 if ( $old_status == 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' ) {
 $post_id = get_the_ID($post);
  if (is_single($post_id)){
 $post_title = get_the_title($post);
 $post_url = get_permalink($post);
 $message = __('Post updated','pmc').":\n";
 $message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

   // Send notification
   pmc_send($message);
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: what action are you trying to use it on? show us your code.

Comment: Ok added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you can't.

Per the Codex,

> [[`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)] checks if a single post of any post type except attachment and page post types is being displayed.

You're trying to use it on the `transition_post_status` hook, which is not related to page display, and so `is_single()` has no meaning.

#### The Solution

Instead of using `is_single()`, use [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type):

```
if( 'post' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: But its important for the function to know if its a post or a page

Comment: In that case, you're looking for [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type). Something like `if( 'post' == get_post_type( $post ) { ... } ` should do it.

Comment: Yeah thats working!